# iPython 5 keybinding for Option+<key>

Tags: python, ipython, prompt-toolkit

iPython 5 switched to python-prompt-toolkit, and no longer uses readline config (`~/.inputrc`)

On my mac, I have Option+left and Option-right configured as backward-word and forward-word respectively. This works great in my bash shells, and used to work fine in ipython. However it no longer works with ipython 5, as they now just type B and F.

In the ipython source I see [plenty of ways](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/prompt_toolkit/keys.py#L55) of configuring Control+[key] (which is fairly useless on a Mac), but basically zero mentions of the Alt/Option key.

How can I configure ipython to use Option-left and Option-right to move between words?

Comment: Already answered in the documentation: [Binding alt+something, option+something or meta+something -- More about key bindings — prompt_toolkit 3.0.2 documentation](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/advanced_topics/key_bindings.html#binding-alt-something-option-something-or-meta-something)